# Why does this code print the correct string?

Tags: c, string

Our professor wrote this code to demonstrate scanning and printing strings,

```
char flower[7][50];
int i, n;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the name of the flower number %d : ", i + 1);
    scanf("%s", &flower[i][50]);
}
printf("\nEnter the number of the flower you want : ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Flower number %d is %s\n", n, flower[n]);
```

I have been using C for almost 2 years now, and I feel like I grasped the fundamental concepts pretty well. But, for some reason, I just can't understand this piece of code.

Why is `scanf("%s", &flower[i][50])` used here instead of `scanf("%s", flower[i])` or `scanf("%s", &flower[i][0])`? What does that `50` even mean?
Why is the index `n` used rather than `n - 1` in `printf("Name %d is %s\n", n, flower[n])`?

I did ask her about it, but the answers she gave were not very comprehensive. She said that "because we used `i+1` in the loop to print `1` instead of `0`, we are going to use the same index to print the string needed, hence why we use `flower[n]`", which doesn't answer anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I entered the following strings followed by the index :

```
Rose
Lily
Tulip
Orchid
Carnation
Hyacinth
Chrysanthemum
6
```

Output :

```
Hyacinth
```

Comment: She wrote scanf("%s", &flower[i][50]); because she does not know C enough good.:) The for loop where this call is used invokes undefined behavior.:) She should write scanf("%49s", flower[i]); Also the call of printf should look like printf("Flower number %d is %s\n", n, flower[n-1]);

Comment: If you ask for "Why did she ...?" you turn your question in a guessing game, because nobody here knows her reasons. I recommend to ask about the code and your understanding of it. I also recommend to double and triple check that you have copied the most puzzling parts correctly and to make a [mre] of code you want to discuss and can test-run to verify that the result you describe is created by it (because I would like to and for that it is better that everybody here uses the same complete program for discussing ....)

Comment: Your professor's code is wrong, and invokes Undefined Behaviour. She does not know what she is doing.

Comment: You are right, it has to be `&flower[i][0]`. Professors do not always have to be right. And it should be `n-1`.

Comment: @Yunnosch This is indeed the complete code (stripped of the standard libraries and the `main` function signaure). I did triple check, and even tested it multiple times.

Comment: "stripped of the standard libraries and the main function signaure" and [mre] do not play well together. But thanks for double checking. I wanted to explore the less honor-cutting explanation possibilities...

Comment: Input a very long name as flower 7 (try forty-ish characters), you may see that the code does not actually work. (that one writes past the array and nukes a bit of the stack, it forgets to do the scanf for me, but could also crash)

Comment: Is it actually scanning the string into the next array? For example `flower[0][50]` points to the first element of the next array `flower[1]`. And so for the last array `flower[6]` we are going to end up with undefined behavior. Is that what's happening?

Comment: @teapot418 Yes, you are right. It crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if your professor is probably thinking that arrays index from 1 (like they maybe do in some other languages), when they actually index from zero in C.

This is evidenced by this:

```
printf("Enter the name of the flower number %d : ", i + 1);
```

And then this:

```
scanf("%s", &flower[i][50]);
```

`&flower[i][50]` is the same as `&flower[i + 1][0]`.

However, that is not a valid address on the final iteration of the loop, because the actual array indexes from [0] to [6]. This will invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I thought I was missing something. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I recommend to keep a "loophole" by phrasing something like "The most likely explanation is that ...." because you do not really know what the professor was thinking. I do however agree with the technical parts of your post. Questions for input which is counting one-based indexing is widely spread, assuming that a corresponding thinking of arrays is present seems a little daring. Let's try to find the most honorable explanation.... which, seeing the undefined behaviour, is still a blow to their competence.

Comment: @Yunnosch Updated to be less insulting.

Comment: Can you explain why `&flower[i][50]` is the same as `&flower[i + 1][0]`? `&flower[i][50]` points to somewhere that have not been reserved.

Comment: @AliSafapour This is a proper 2-dimensional array of `[7][50]`. All the bytes are contiguous. Maybe you are getting confused with a (commonly used) array like `char *x[7]` where each member is an array that needs to be allocated separately.